Inception gives verylow accuracy in isic dataset
I am trying to run a vanilla Inception V3 transfer learning model on the isic dataset of 2239 images of training and 118 images for testing assorted in classified folders of the images. This dataset has been taken from the kaggle datasets in skin cancer images.
The aim of this is to classify the images into the different cancer classifications(eg.> melannmoma , nevus , vascular lession , etc (9 classes in total))
The vanilla build is giving a very low accuracy on the training and even lowerd validation accuracy and the graphs formed are with spikes everywhere on the kaggle platform.
on some epochs , the val accuracy and accuracy becomes 0 while loss shows 1000000.000000 which causes such abnormal spikes during the ploting.
Plotly and matplot lib were used for plotting the result after training.
i do not understand the reason behind such low accuracy and such abnormal spikes during training.
the accuracy after 25 epochs is 59.98% and val_accuracy is 37.89%
expecting accuracy of over 80% and val_accuracy of >=70%
Please help me understand the problem with the code and how to increase the accuracy of the model.
dataset link :
The code :-
getting the paths of the images
data_dir_train = pathlib.Path("/kaggle/input/skin-cancer9-classesisic/Skin cancer ISIC The International Skin Imaging Collaboration/Train/")
data_dir_test = pathlib.Path("/kaggle/input/skin-cancer9-classesisic/Skin cancer ISIC The International Skin Imaging Collaboration/Test/")
image_count_train = len(list(data_dir_train.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count_train)
image_count_test = len(list(data_dir_test.glob('*/*.jpg')))
print(image_count_test)

The training , validation and testing datasets :-

batch_size = 16
img_height = 224
img_width = 224 
rnd_seed = 123 
random.seed(rnd_seed)

train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir_train,
    
    validation_split = 0.2 , 
    subset = "training" ,
    seed = 123 , 
    
    image_size = (img_height , img_width) ,
    batch_size = batch_size,
    label_mode = "categorical"
)

# The validation dataset for using the validation split of all the images 
val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir_train,
    
    validation_split = 0.2 , 
    subset = "validation" , 
    seed = 123 , 
    image_size = (img_height , img_width) , 
    batch_size = batch_size ,
    label_mode = "categorical"
)

# The testing dataset for using the test split among all the testing images 
test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir_test , 
    
    validation_split = 0.9 , 
    subset = "validation" , 
    seed = 123 , 
    shuffle = True ,
    image_size = (img_height , img_width) , 
    batch_size = batch_size ,
    label_mode = "categorical"
)


#printing the class names of all the images in the entire image dataset:-
class_names = train_ds.class_names
print(class_names)

The model being used :-
base_model = InceptionV3(
    weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(224 , 224 , 3)
)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False


x = base_model.output
x = Flatten()(x)
final_pred = Dense(len(class_names) , activation = "softmax")(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input , outputs = final_pred)
model.summary()



model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy() , optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0001) , metrics = ['accuracy'])



with tf.device('/device:GPU:0'):
    history = model.fit(
        x = train_ds,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=val_ds,
        steps_per_epoch=len(train_ds),
        validation_steps=len(val_ds)
    )

The code for plotting the results in the history after training :-
#matplotlib :- 

tr_acc = history.history['accuracy']
tr_loss = history.history['loss']
val_acc = history.history['val_accuracy']
val_loss = history.history['val_loss']

epochs = [i+1 for i in range(len(tr_acc))]

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 8))
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.plot(epochs, tr_loss, 'r', label='Train Loss')
plt.plot(epochs, val_loss, 'g', label='Valid Loss')
plt.title('Loss')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Loss')

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.plot(epochs, tr_acc, 'r', label='Train Accuracy')
plt.plot(epochs, val_acc, 'g', label='Valid Accuracy')
plt.title('Accuracy')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('Accuracy')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()




#plotly :- 
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['val_loss'], name="val_loss"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['loss'], name="loss"),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['val_accuracy'], name="val accuracy"),
    secondary_y=True,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter( y=history.history['accuracy'], name="val accuracy"),
    secondary_y=True,
)
# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Loss/Accuracy of LSTM Model"
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Epoch")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>primary</b> Loss", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>secondary</b> Accuracy", secondary_y=True)

fig.show()

